What's the phase of different points in a standing wave?
The equation my book gives for a standing wave's disposition from it's equallibrium is:
$$\displaystyle y=2A\cos \left( \frac{2\pi x}{\lambda}\right) \sin \left( \frac{2\pi t}{T}\right)$$
Where the first term is the amplitude. And the phase is $\frac{2\pi t}{T }$
My book later says though that in a given moment $t$, between two successive nodes the phase is the same for each point in that area, which makes sense given that the phase is only time dependent based on the equation. But then it says that left and right of these nodes (in a distance less than $\frac {\lambda} {2}$) the phase is not the same, and that the difference in phase between any point in these two areas is $\pi$ radians. Could someone explain why that's the case? Why should the point's whereabouts matter if phase is only time dependent?

Here is a gif file which shows the displacement of particles (y-axis) against mean positions of particles for a standing wave.

There are positions where the particles do note move - nodes (red dots) whose separation is $\lambda/2$.
Between to nodes all the particles move in phase with one another with the maximum amplitude being at positions which are called antinodes.
Particles on either side of a node and within $\lambda/2$ of a node have a phase difference of $\pi\,/\,180^\circ$.
The time variation of the particles is given by the term $\displaystyle \sin \left( \frac{2\pi t}{T}\right)$ and the amplitude envelope is given by the term $2A\cos \left( \frac{2\pi x}{\lambda}\right) $.

But isn't the phase only the term 2πt/T? Therefore the phase is only dependent on time

Look at the gif.  You can see the parts which are in phase with one another, $\displaystyle \sin \left( \frac{2\pi t}{T}\right)$ and those which are $\pi$ out of phase with them, $\displaystyle -\sin \left( \frac{2\pi t}{T}\right)$.

I understand that conceptually but not mathematically, if Φ=2πt/T as I'm saying (unless that's wrong) where is the difference between points?

Effectively you have a $\displaystyle \sin \left( \frac{2\pi t}{T}\right)$ term between two nodes (all particles in phase with each other but with differing amplitudes )  and a $\displaystyle \sin \left( \frac{2\pi t}{T}-\pi\right)$ term in the next inter-node region (all particles in phase with each other but $\pi$ out of phase with particles in an adjacent inter-node region).
